# C++, содержит ли стандартная библиотека компонент с семантикой байтового потока, который является более быстрым, чем std::stringstream

Tags: c++, stringstream

Скажите, пожалуйста, какое средство из состава стандартной библиотеки `C++` я могу использовать для работы с потоком байтов в памяти (не в файле)?

Мне нужна следующая семантика:

- В одном месте я беру объект потока и пишу в него байты (возможно, последовательности байтов);
- В некоторых других местах я хочу давать такой поток только на чтение (например, через ссылку на более базовый класс).

Я полистал документацию и увидел только две основные разновидности потоков:

- fstream;
- stringstream.

Со `fstream` все понятно, он только для файлов.
Ко `stringstream` имеется ряд претензий.

Первое - скорость записи, она очень маленькая, на уровне 0.5 ГБ в секунду, даже если писать 0.5 ГБ одним куском в поток, в котором необходимое место уже зарезервировано. Мне точно известно, что на моем железе за одну секунду я могу скопировать 5 ГБ памяти (через `memcpy`).

Второе - я не уверен, что методы `stringstream` являются виртуальными, и что я могу передавать объект типа `stingstream` в функцию, которая принимает ссылку на `istringstream`.

Можно ли реализовать то, что я хочу, без написания собственных велосипедов?

Comment: Видимо, нет. Он даже не наследует iss.

Comment: Если для работы с потоком байтов в памяти, можно напрямую работать с буфером  потока, это увеличит скорость.

Comment: Абстракции быстрыми не бывают...

Comment: У меня есть код, где я записываю картинку в виде ppm. Так вот есть запись старым сишным спрособом `fwrite(... "%d %d %d ",r,g,b)` и модным плюсовым `out << r << ' ' << g << ' ' << b << ' ';` - разница в скорости - почти 10 раз. (2 секунды против 0.21). `sprintf` + `out.rdbuf()->sputn` выравнивают ситуацию до статистической погрешности.

Comment: Я разбирался-разбирался, в итоге попробовал написать собственную реализацию в лоб, и она оказалась во много раз быстрее стандартного компонента `std::stringstream`...